# Quartz scheduler not triggering inside of docker container

Tags: c#, background-service

I have a background service that is using quartz scheduler to send out emails at a certain time , when running it with project it runs fine but it I try to run it in docker container it doesn't trigger.
Do I need to add anything in docker file

Comment: Could be time zone issue? Docker container is most likely configured to use UTC while your host machine is probably in some other time zone.

Comment: Check both are on the same timezone UTC and the times are the same

Comment: Just to confirm: the machine where it does work is in UTC zone? Otherwise: https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/issues/1267